# Segmentation fault with numpy "X.T.dot(X)" with "import cplex"

Tags: python, numpy, python-3.5, cplex

I am working with Python3.5 (w/ Anaconda) with Cplex12.7.1 on Mac.

I recently found out that "Segmentation fault: 11" occurs when I run X.T.dot(X) with numpy when I have imported cplex beforehand, as follows.

```
import cplex
import numpy as np
X = np.random.randn(5, 3)
Z = X.T.dot(X)
```

Can anyone advise me how I can avoid the segmentation fault?

Without "import cplex", it works fine. It also works without an error if I first copy X.T and then multiply, as follows.

```
import cplex
import numpy as np
X = np.random.randn(5, 3)
Y = X.T.copy()
Z = Y.dot(X)
```

Comment: The operation that you're doing does not require the use of cplex. Maybe something is wrong with your installation of cplex.

Comment: Cplex Python APIs work fine: it can solve LP and QP without errors. The segmentation fault occurs when I use cplex together with the particular numpy code X.T.dot(X) (to implement more complex algorithms).

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce with a clean environment using CPLEX 12.7.1, conda 4.4.10, Python 3.5.4, numpy 1.14.0, Mac OS X 10.10.5. Maybe you need to do a `conda update conda`? What happens if you install another instance of Miniconda in an alternate location and try again?

Comment: I found that Miniconda + numpy/cplex worked fine.

Comment: `conda update conda` on Anaconda did not help.